# How to fix ZFS pool once spare replacement done or how to correct spare replacement

Tags: zfs, zpool, degraded

I have a ZFS pool in the current state:

```
[root@SERVER-abc ~]# zpool status -v DATAPOOL
  pool: DATAPOOL
 state: DEGRADED
status: One or more devices has experienced an error resulting in data
        corruption.  Applications may be affected.
action: Restore the file in question if possible.  Otherwise restore the
        entire pool from backup.
   see: https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/msg/ZFS-8000-8A
  scan: resilvered 18.5M in 00:00:01 with 0 errors on Wed Jan  5 19:10:50 2022
config:`

        NAME                                              STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        DATAPOOL                                          DEGRADED     0     0     0
          raidz2-0                                        DEGRADED     0     0     0
            gptid/14c707c6-f16c-11e8-b117-0cc47a2ba44e    DEGRADED     0     0    17  too many errors
            spare-1                                       ONLINE       0     0    17
              gptid/168342c5-f16c-11e8-b117-0cc47a2ba44e  ONLINE       0     0     0
              gptid/1bfaa607-f16c-11e8-b117-0cc47a2ba44e  ONLINE       0     0     0
            gptid/1875501a-f16c-11e8-b117-0cc47a2ba44e    ONLINE       0     0    30
            gptid/1a16d37c-f16c-11e8-b117-0cc47a2ba44e    ONLINE       0     0    29
        spares
          gptid/1bfaa607-f16c-11e8-b117-0cc47a2ba44e      INUSE     currently in use

errors: Permanent errors have been detected in the following files:

        DATAPOOL/VMS/ubuntu_1804_LTS_ustrich-m6i87@auto-2022-01-04_11-41:<0x1>
        <0x1080a>:<0x1>
        <0x182a>:<0x1>
        DATAPOOL/VMS/ubuntu_1804_LTS_ustrich-m6i87:<0x1>
        <0x16fa>:<0x1>
```

This is a zpool with 4 + 1 spare drives. Something happened and suddenly the spare ist pairing automatically with the other drive as spare-1.

This is unexpected to me, as:

1. Why did the spare not replace the degraded drive?
2. How to find out why the spare jumped to spare-1?
3. Is it possible (or even recommended/possible) to get the spare back and then to replace the degraded drive?

Goal is to rescue the pool without having to get tons of data from the backup, but in core I want to understand what happened and why. And how to deal with those situations as in 'best practices'.

Tanks a bunch! :)

System is: SuperMicro, TrueNAS-12.0-U4.1, zfs-2.0.4-3

Edit: Changed output from zpool status -x to zpool status -v DATAPOOL

Edit2: As of now I understant that first 168342c5 seem to have an error and the spare (1bfaa607) jumped in. After that 14c707c6 degraded as well.

Edit3, Additional question: as all drives (except the one in spare-1) seem to have CKSUM errors - what does that indicate? Cabling? HBA? All drives are dying simultaneously?

Latest Update, after `zpool clear` and `zpool scrub DATAPOOL` it seems clear, that alot has happened and there is no way to rescue the pool:

```
  pool: DATAPOOL
 state: DEGRADED
status: One or more devices is currently being resilvered.  The pool will
        continue to function, possibly in a degraded state.
action: Wait for the resilver to complete.
  scan: resilver in progress since Thu Jan  6 16:18:05 2022
        1.82T scanned at 1.55G/s, 204G issued at 174M/s, 7.82T total
        40.8G resilvered, 2.55% done, 12:44:33 to go
config:

        NAME                                              STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        DATAPOOL                                          DEGRADED     0     0     0
          raidz2-0                                        DEGRADED     0     0     0
            gptid/14c707c6-f16c-11e8-b117-0cc47a2ba44e    DEGRADED     0     0   156  too many errors
            spare-1                                       DEGRADED     0     0     0
              gptid/168342c5-f16c-11e8-b117-0cc47a2ba44e  DEGRADED     0     0   236  too many errors
              gptid/1bfaa607-f16c-11e8-b117-0cc47a2ba44e  ONLINE       0     0     0  (resilvering)
            gptid/1875501a-f16c-11e8-b117-0cc47a2ba44e    DEGRADED     0     0   182  too many errors
            gptid/1a16d37c-f16c-11e8-b117-0cc47a2ba44e    DEGRADED     0     0   179  too many errors
        spares
          gptid/1bfaa607-f16c-11e8-b117-0cc47a2ba44e      INUSE     currently in use
```

I'll check all smart stats now.

Answer (score 1):

Is this a 4-disk RAIDZ2?

Did you choose that layout over ZFS mirrors?

Can you show the output of `zpool status -v`?

Please also run a `zpool clear` and follow the results/progress.

Comment: `Is this a 4-disk RAIDZ2?
 Did you choose that layout over ZFS mirrors?`

Yes, I was young and didn't know better m|

Comment: `Please also run a zpool clear and follow the results/progress.` I just cleared and do a new scrub. As of now all looks okay in zpool status, but the first smart problems are incoming via email from the system.